# Why Asp.Net SignalR invoke OnDisconnect in hub many times with the same ConnectionId?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I find the signalr server invoke OnDisconnect with the same ConnectionId more than one time ? Normally, this would not happen

I don't know how this happened，Could anyone help me ?

thank you

Comment: I used LongPollingTransport in the .Net Client(winform)

Comment: How did you server handle the OnDisconnect event? From the description above, the server waits until the disconnect timeout period has elapsed and fire the `OnDisconnected` event continuously.